# How to cite a google survey in an original paper?

Tags: citations, citation-style

Is it even possible to cite a google survey (designed by yourself) in an original paper? [via docs.google.com]

Any explanations would be thanked!

Regards.

Comment: Can you please explain why or how you would want to cite an inherently transient thing like an online survey?

Comment: @jakebeal: Sorry what do you mean by inherently transient?

Comment: An online survey form is not an archival publication, nor a long-term community maintained resource.  There is no reason to expect it will still exist in any meaningful manner in 5 years.

Comment: @jakebeal: yes right; and what can I do if no institution would cooperate to publish the survey, and I need the results to be seen by the academic society?

Answer (score 5):

If you designed the survey and this is the first paper in which you discuss the results, then you don't need to cite it you need to present it as original research with all the detail that requires. The fact that it's a google survey doesn't seem especially important, but you can probably find a good review article on methodological considerations for Web based surveys.

Comment: Thanks Tim,
Something that makes me worry is the fact that google surveys seem to be editable by the survey owner. What do you think?

Comment: @AmirHosseinKiani and isn't that owner you? The fact that the owner of a paper survey could lie about which questions were asked has never stopped is from using those. Research ethics applies as usual.

Comment: yes that owner is me. I'm just curious on how/why should the reviewers trust the statistical results of my survey! How do they know that I've not changed the result by myself?

Comment: @AmirHosseinKiani they don't know as such that you haven't changed the results, but my point is that the same is true of all surveys (and nearly all empirical research). Academia is built on trust augmented with skepticism. If you report something outlandish, it won't make it through peer review. If you report something interesting but fabricated, it will eventually catch someone's eye for a replication. None of this is specific to Google surveys, but a good methodology paper might have some advice nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim!
I'll look for some methodology papers.